# Range hood installation for non built-in stove

Tags: kitchens, vent, stove, range

I'm looking to buy a range hood for our stove. The hood will be externally vented through the roof (1 story house) since it's on an interior wall.  It seems that most of the wall mounted chimney units assume that the range itself is flush or almost flush to the wall, since they have a depth of around 18".

We have a free standing stove, (i.e., not built into the cabinets) with no cabinetry on the wall the stove is against and if I measure from the wall to the back of the back burners, it's about 10", so 18" from the wall will not really cover the full stove surface, and won't cover half of the front two burners.

Does this mean that I need to install an island model instead of a wall mounted model hood? Or is it possible/desirable to add some sort of spacing so that the wall mounted unit hangs out further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stove slides back to the wall. Your venting mounts to the wall - how much over hang of the stove and how much height you have to be able move pans in and out has some factor in this and aesthetics play a part as well - because if you do not have a perfect overhang of the vent - the fan will cause forced air venting.

The Vent you purchased may or may not be suitable for your taste - for example you might not want it to sit back a little but instead cover the entire stove area. Your vent might be for a cook top and not a stove or for a smaller stove.

Many if not most people prefer the unit to cover the burners in their entirety - I will assume your local code does not require a vent for the stove, if it did there might be some local laws that specify what is acceptable or not acceptable.

I would suggest a properly sized vent - typically they are 24 inches deep.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't bought anything yet, but have been looking at specs for wall mounted chimney vents. So it seems I need to be looking for deeper models. 24" will still not completely cover the front burners, but will definitely cover most of them.

Comment: Our old, but good quality, Vent-A-Hood is only 20" deep but still effectively evacuates the fumes from the front burners of our GE 30" wide electric slide in range.  I am sure 24" would be better, although I sometimes hit my head on a bottom corner of ours. The front top of the range is 29" from the back wall. I have the hood positioned so the bottom is 29" above the top of the range, 66" off the floor (I am 70" tall in bare feet). Ours is a 1-speed and it is noisy. It has a squirrel cage fan designed to condense grease fumes in a box which is removable for cleaning.